# Can Ubuntu play a video via cron job?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, cron, crontab, cronjob

I'm developing a display system for a paint shop.
I've set up a computer with Ubuntu to run the video and display it on a TV, running a PHP script that should update the video every hour via the internet.

The script is set to run via cron, executed once every hour (@hourly). Almost the entire script runs perfectly, but the last line where it executes VLC Media Player to display the video fails silently.
If the script is run via command line (`php /path/to/cron.php`), VLC Media Player starts perfectly. But when it is run in cron, it does not.

The thought I get is, that jobs running via cron simply doesn't have the ability to run applications with a visible GUI, but I really hope that is not the answer.

Please help me crack this one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display something on an X server the X client (like `vlc`) requires an environment variable `DISPLAY` to be set which defines network address of the X server. In almost all cases (one local X server) it should be assigned to `:0`.

You can set that variable from your script or just run `bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 vlc $vlcopts"` instead (of course replacing `$vlcopts`).

Comment: This is fantastic! I never thought of the DISPLAY variable. Well, you may think that this wasn't a hard one, but you sure solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

@hourly screen -d -m vlc-wrapper /path/to/file/foo.flv --novideo --volume 700 --repeat --rc-fake-tty

To make vlc work. There is a detailed process here: 
http://michaelchrisco.com/wiki/index.php?title=Set_up_VLC_as_a_cron_job